Can I use this trick to write the one-body Laplacian as a two-body Laplacian?
Suppose we have a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H} = L^{2}(\Omega)$, where omega is some finite torus $\Omega = [-L/2,L/2]^{3}$, with $L \ge 1$. Wave functions of $\varphi_{p}(x) = L^{-3/2}e^{i\langle p, x \rangle}$ form a basis for $L^{2}(\Omega)$ and, consequently, tensor products of such wave functions $\{\varphi_{p} \otimes \varphi_{q}\}_{p,q}$ form a basis for $L^{2}(\Omega) \otimes L^{2}(\Omega) \cong L^{2}(\Omega^{2})$.
For $A$ a linear operator on $L^{2}(\Omega^{2})$, suppose I have the following sum:
$$\sum_{p, k, m, n, s, r} |p|^{2}\langle A(\varphi_{m}\otimes \varphi_{n}), \varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}\rangle\langle \varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}, A(\varphi_{s}\otimes \varphi_{r})\rangle a^{*}_{m}a^{*}_{n}a_{s}a_{r}$$
I can write this expression as:
$$\sum_{p, k, m, n, s, r} \langle A(\varphi_{m}\otimes \varphi_{n}),|p|^{2} \varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}\rangle\langle \varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}, A(\varphi_{s}\otimes \varphi_{r})\rangle a^{*}_{m}a^{*}_{n}a_{s}a_{r} \\
= \sum_{p, k, m, n, s, r} \langle A(\varphi_{m}\otimes \varphi_{n}), (-\Delta_{x})\varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}\rangle\langle \varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}, A(\varphi_{s}\otimes \varphi_{r})\rangle a^{*}_{m}a^{*}_{n}a_{s}a_{r} \\
=-\sum_{p, k, m, n, s, r} \langle \Delta_{x}A(\varphi_{m}\otimes \varphi_{n}), \varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}\rangle\langle \varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}, A(\varphi_{s}\otimes \varphi_{r})\rangle a^{*}_{m}a^{*}_{n}a_{s}a_{r} \\
= -\sum_{m,n,s,r}\langle \varphi_{m}\otimes \varphi_{n}, A^{*}\Delta_{x}A(\varphi_{r}\otimes \varphi_{s})\rangle a_{m}^{*}a_{n}^{*}a_{r}a_{s},$$
where I used the resolution of identity. My notation $\Delta_{x}$ means the Laplacian acting only on the $x$ coordinate (the first wave functions).
I wanted to obtain the same expression, but with the one-body Laplacian $-\Delta_{x}$ replaced by the two body Laplacian $-\Delta_{x}-\Delta_{y}$. I think this can be done in the first step of the above reasoning. My idea is to write, alternatively:
$$\sum_{p, k, m, n, s, r} \langle A(\varphi_{m}\otimes \varphi_{n}),|p|^{2} \varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}\rangle\langle \varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}, A(\varphi_{s}\otimes \varphi_{r})\rangle a^{*}_{m}a^{*}_{n}a_{s}a_{r} \\
= \sum_{p, k, m, n, s, r} \langle A(\varphi_{m}\otimes \varphi_{n}), (\frac{1}{2}|p|^{2}+\frac{1}{2}|k|^{2})\varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}\rangle\langle \varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}, A(\varphi_{s}\otimes \varphi_{r})\rangle a^{*}_{m}a^{*}_{n}a_{s}a_{r} \\
= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{p, k, m, n, s, r} \langle A(\varphi_{m}\otimes \varphi_{n}), (-\Delta_{x}-\Delta_{y})\varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}\rangle\langle \varphi_{p}\otimes \varphi_{k}, A(\varphi_{s}\otimes \varphi_{r})\rangle a^{*}_{m}a^{*}_{n}a_{s}a_{r}.$$
The identity seems to hold because, in the end, I am summing over all possible $p$ and $k$ anyway. But I am not sure this step is, in fact, correct. Can anyone help me clarify this point?
